# In MongoDB design can I have hundreds of thousands of strings of length 10 inside an array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, database-design, database

I am designing a database where suppose a user if following some celebrities now I have made two tables for that one named as user_follow where I am placing user and corresponding to that I am having celebrities he/she is following in an array (e.g "user_name": "mak", "follows": ["Tom_cruise", "Brad_pitt"]) and the second table name is celebrity_followers where I am putting celebrities corresponding to the array of user names who are following the celebrity (e.g celeb_name: "Tom_cruise", "followers": ["mak", "user2"]) now if I have any update for say tom_cruise I will go into celebrity_followers and corresponding to that celeb and I will send updates to every user named in the array for Tom_cruise now if any user wants to unfollow any celebrity I will go inside user_follow table and I will delete the celeb name corresponding to that user now my question is that for any user he will follow at max 100 celebs so I can easily have 500 elements inside an array in mongoDB but my question is that for any particular celeb I can have 100000 of users now to have them inside an array will that cause any trouble in performance for e.g (when user unfollow delete them from celeb table or to send updates for any celeb) or storing or in any possible way?

Comment: I was about to format your answer and split it into paragraphs, then I realised it was all one paragraph. Having one block of code/text makes your question **very** difficult to read/understand.

Answer (score 0):

**Side note** Whatever a lakh is (I'll take for granted that it means "a sh...load"). Please refrain from using native number names. What number would you associate with a "Schock" or a "Gros"? ;)

You have a conceptual problem here. As of the time of this writing, BSON documents are limited to 16MB of size. So storing references to followers at a celeb's document may lead to maxing out the size, making the document unwritable.

It is unlikely, however, that a user will follow sh...loads of celebs, let's say a few hundred of them at most. This should fit into the the user documents:

```js
{
  "_id": "CoolUser",
  "foo": "bar",
  "follows":[
    IdOfCelebA,
    IdOfCelebB
  ]
}
```

So finding all followers of the given celeb `CelebA` would be as easy as:

```js
db.users.find({ "follows": CelebA._id })
```

and finding all celebs a given user `UserA` follows as easy as:

```js
db.celebs.find({ _id:{ "$in": UserA.follows } })
```

Removing the same user from the set of followers becomes obvious:

```js
db.users.update(
  { _id: UserA._id },
  { $pull:{ follows: "IdOfCelebA" } },
  {
    multi: false // Default, but leaving out the query part and setting this to true would remove a celeb from all users
  }
)
```

Comment: A [lakh](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh) is 100,000. But I agree - native numbers should be avoided.